# Facebook insights - Previews, Followers, Responsiveness are missing from API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

In the facebook insights dashboard they include:
"Page Previews", "Page Followers" and "Page Responsiveness" all given for a date range.

However, the API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/insights - does not include these metrics. Is there any way to get these metrics from the API? (for each day in a daterange)